# Add multiple lines of text to JTextArea

Tags: java, string, jtextarea

I have a string stored with a lot of text, and looks something like this

```
String aLotOfText = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa " + variable1 + ". /n/n"
"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb " + variable2 + ". /n/n" //and so on...
```

When I try to add it to a JTextArea with the setText() method, it all becomes a single line, including the "/n"s. Like this:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 1. /n/nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb 2. /n/n
```

How do I get it in each line?

Edit:
This is my JTextArea and JPanel. **I have changed /n to \n** but now only one line will show

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    konsol = new JTextArea();
    konsol.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane konsolSP = new JScrollPane(konsol);
    konsolSP.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Server Output"));
    panel.add(konsolSP, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    konsol.setRows(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `/n` instead of `\n` which is the appropriate newline escape sequence.

Edit: In order to show you how I got mine to work, I posted the smallest compilable code snippet:

```
public class JTATest extends JFrame {
    public JTATest() {
        JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
        jta.setText("lol\n\nlol");
        //jta.setRows(50); // You do not actually need this
        this.add(jta);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTATest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Things happen :P

Comment: Wait I stilll get the same result, but now just a single line. Like this:
`aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 1.` and the rest never shows up

Comment: That sounds like the formatting of your JTextArea is the problem.

Comment: Try something like jta.setRows(100) and see if it displays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143325/discussion-between-dddjewelsbbb-and-bassusour).